# CalcHEP and FeynCalc giving different amplitudes--spin averaging?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, beyond-the-standard-model, software

I've done a simple amplitude calculation involving neutrinos and fermions scattering or annihilating through a BSM gauge boson.  I'm checking with FeynCalc and CalcHEP, but the two are giving different results; the kinematics are the same, but the factors of 2 are different.  The processes are

$$
f \bar{f} \rightarrow \nu\bar\nu
$$
and
$$
f \nu \rightarrow f\nu
$$

both via the exchange of some heavy spin-1 mediator.  When I did the calculation in FeynCalc, I input the spin-averaging factors of 1/4 in by hand, and got a result that matched the calculation I did on paper.  However, the results from CalcHEP differ by a factor of 8 (scattering) or a factor of 4 (annihilation).  I'm wondering if this has something to do with how CalcHEP does spin averaging, or how it treats neutrinos (I've noticed you have to tell it neutrinos are left-handed, but you also need to include a Lorentz factor of $1-\gamma^5$ in vertices involving neutrinos; is there some redundancy here?).  Or are there other common gotcha's that might cause CalcHEP to give the incorrect factors of 2?

Comment: $1-\gamma^5$ is not a Lorentz factor, but proportional to the projector for your left handed fields. The Lorentz factor refers usually to the object $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta}}$

Comment: @Triatticus CalcHEP calls all of the gamma matrices the "Lorentz part"

Comment: I see, well this isn't really a question about physics but a specific software, it will be up to the respective manuals that explain what goes into each calculation. I only ever really use feyncalc and not much else so I don't have much to say as I haven't even heard of CalcHEP before. Maybe someone out here does know but it might be even easier to reach out to the writers of the code.